# How to create logical index for rows not containing specific characters

Tags: r, subset, grepl

I'm attempting to subset all rows by names that don't contain the + symbol, but can not figure it out. Consider:

```
df <- data.frame(Models = c("m1+m2", "m3+m4", "m5"), Values = rep(1:3))
df[,3] <- grepl("+", df[,1])
df

  Models Values   V3
1  m1+m2      1 TRUE
2  m3+m4      2 TRUE
3     m5      3 TRUE
```

Shouldn't row 3 be FALSE?

Comment: `grepl("\\+", df[,1])` because `+` is a special character in regex ore `grepl("+", df[,1], fixed=TRUE)` to turn off the regex and match on the literal.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks! Feel free to add as answer and I'll accept. Cheers!